# missing value imputation in r

Tags: r, missing-data

I have several columns like this:

```
0.277289310  
0.275562150  
0.265427900  
NA 
0.259514200  
0.277133810
NA
```

NA is random, I want to use the nearest average to impute the NA, if it's the last one then use the previous value. 
How should I do that?

Comment: what does nearest average mean?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the relationship among the columns? What is the relationship among the rows? I ask because it's probably rather unlikely you want to do what you think you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vanilla R solution that is over 2x faster than Richard's solution.

```
vec <- c(NA, 0.277289310, 0.275562150, NA, 0.265427900, NA, NA, NA, 0.259514200, 0.277133810, NA)

ups   <- c(if (is.na(vec[1])) NA else NULL, which(c(diff(is.na(vec))) == 1))
downs <- c(which(c(0, diff(is.na(vec))) == -1), if (is.na(tail(vec, 1))) NA else NULL)
narle <- rle(is.na(vec))

vec[is.na(vec)] <- rep((vec[ups] + vec[downs]) / 2, narle$lengths[narle$values])
if (is.na(ups[1])) vec[seq_len(downs[1] - 1)] <- vec[downs[1]]
if (is.na(tail(downs, 1))) vec[tail(ups, 1):length(vec)] <- vec[tail(ups, 1)]

# [1] 0.2772893 0.2772893 0.2755622 0.2704950 0.2654279 0.2624710 0.2624710 0.2624710 0.25951420.2771338 0.2771338
```

Some benchmarks:

```
# > microbenchmark(richard_srivens_solution(vec), my_solution(vec))
# Unit: microseconds
#                           expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  richard_srivens_solution(vec) 262.232 315.6010 501.4830 519.6025 2146.601   100
#               my_solution(vec)  98.891 141.5545 201.0715 213.7605  714.621   100
```

If you want some more explanation, keep reading. The heart of this are the two statements `which(diff(is.na(vec)) == 1)` and `which(c(0, diff(is.na(vec))) == -1)` which give (for the above `vec`) the values `c(3,5,10)` and `c(2,5,9)`, respectively. In other words, these are the positions of transitions from a non-NA to an NA, and transitions from an NA to a non-NA, respectively.

If you think it about it for a few minutes, you'll see this is all the information we need: we can just average pairs of these values (being slightly careful about the end points), and assign them to the missing values of the original vector. We only need to be careful to replicate these averages for consecutive sequences of missing values. But this can be precisely accomplished with the `rle` function.

[Edited solution slightly because performance didn't hold up on larger vectors (it does now).]

Answer (score 3):

Try a combination of `na.approx` and `na.locf` from the `zoo` package

```
x <- c(0.27728931, 0.27556215, 0.2654279, NA, 0.2595142, 0.27713381, NA)
library(zoo)
na.locf(na.approx(x, na.rm=FALSE))
# [1] 0.2772893 0.2755622 0.2654279 0.2624710 0.2595142 0.2771338 0.2771338
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xx
[1] 0.2755622 0.2654279        NA 0.2595142 0.2771338        NA

for(i in 1:length(xx)) if(is.na(xx[i]))
        xx[i] = ifelse(is.na(xx[i+1]),     xx[i-1],    (xx[i-1]+xx[i+1])/2)

xx
[1] 0.2755622 0.2654279 0.2624710 0.2595142 0.2771338 0.2771338
```

Comment: Using @Robert Krzyzanowski example `vec`, I get a different result using your code.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't look for chains of `NA`s